# Can't make GDAL work on Python 3.7 from Anaconda

Tags: python, gdal, anaconda

I am trying to install GDAL on an clean Anaconda environment (Python 3.7.11) but it fails when imported in the Python console. It does work fine in another environment (Python 3.6). GDAL package is from the main channel (3.0.2) for both (a simple `conda install gdal`). I can't figure out why it fails in 3.7. here is what it says: (can't find the module)

[image]

Comment: please don't  post pictures of error messages

Comment: ok, I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was trying to `import gdal` when now the correct way is to `from osgeo import gdal` or `import osgeo.gdal as gdal` Module instalation was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
# Create a new environment

conda create -n gis python=3.7 anaconda

# Activate the environment

conda activate gis

# Install gdal

conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

Comment: Installing the anaconda package and then the gdal module through conda-forge does work, but it installs a pretty old version of gdal (2.3.3) instead of version 3.4.1

Comment: I think, it is not possible to install a different version and you can have problems when you import modules. You should work with this version.

Comment: Anaconda automatically finds the compatible version. You can try another version of python like 3.8 or 3.9 if you want to work with the latest versions.

Comment: what does the "anaconda" command do in the conda create? installs all the anaconda tools? why doesn't it work simply installing the gdal package?

Comment: Install all the necessary packages for your environment, also jupyter notebook or conda-pack, etc.

Comment: because gdal depends on other compatible packages

Comment: but shouldn't installing gdal package resolve its necessary dependencies?

Comment: Depends if you do an online or offline installation. But if you work with anaconda it is necessary to install all the dependencies, to avoid problems in the future.